# How to create a swipe button like this?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, layout

I want to create a dual side swipe button which gives haptic feedback on reaching the end. The image is attached.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIECf.png

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question with a simple answer, but ill try to give you a general direction on how to go about implementing something like this:

You need handle Touch events on your button, yourself.
something like:

```
  

          button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
            {
    
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) 
                {
                    switch(event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                             // touch down code
                             break;
    
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                             // touch move code
                             break;
    
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
                            // touch up code
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

In onTouch, you need to do two things:

1. Move the button to the appropriate location, base on the motion of the user's finger.
   for this, you should probably store the position of ACTION_DOWN, and then calculate relative movement in ACTION_MOVE and move your button to match it.
   If you want your button to only move along some axis, you need to calculate the appropriate position on this axis, yourself.
2. in ACTION_UP, check the position of your button, and if its close enough to where you want your swipe to end, execute the action